# Анимация пунктира svg

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

Есть линия в svg. Нужно сделать из нее пунктирную линию (это не проблема) и анимировать ее рост. Без пунктира это получается без проблем, а вот с ним никак. Буду рад помощи.

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">

  <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8
    s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41
    C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z"/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Ваш код в студию

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0yy0zL8L/ это просто линия.
https://jsfiddle.net/0yy0zL8L/1/ а вот это пунктир. И работает вообще не так как нужно. Необходимо, чтоб линия росла как в 1 случае

Comment: Анимация должна происходить только 1 раз от начала до конца, без повторов, верно?

Comment: Нет. Извиняюсь что не написал сразу. Должна быть возможность анимировать появление до определенной координаты в любую сторону. Фон неоднородный

Comment: @Curly_Dog в таком случае, вам поможет только d3.js либо другие подобные библиотеки. На чистом js (без библиотек) могу предложить только вариант с единоразовой прорисовкой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, сделать две фигуры, с разными настройками контура:

```css
.path2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 10;
}
.path1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
}
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">
  
  
<path class="path1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8
    s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41
    C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z"/>

<path class="path2" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8
    s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41
    C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z"/>
</svg>
```

Для случая, если фон неоднородный, нашлось решение, например с использованием библиотеки [Raphael](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/)

```js
var animateLine = function(canvas, colorNumber, pathString) {
 var line = canvas.path(pathString).attr({
  stroke: colorNumber
 });
 var length = line.getTotalLength();
 $('path').animate({
  'to': 1
 }, {
  duration: 5000,
  step: function(pos, fx) {
   var offset = length * fx.pos;
   var subpath = line.getSubpath(0, offset);
   canvas.clear();
   canvas.path(subpath).attr({
    stroke: colorNumber,
    "stroke-dasharray":"-",
    "stroke-width": '5'
   });
  }
 });
};


var canvas = new Raphael('dash', 350, 540.1);

var pathString = "M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8 s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41 C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z";
animateLine(canvas, "#000000", pathString);
```

```css
body {
  background: #bdc3c7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #2c3e50, #bdc3c7); 
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c3e50, #bdc3c7); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.min.js"></script>
<div id="dash"></div>
```

Comment: А если фон неоднородный?

Comment: @Curly_Dog Тогда, только со сторонней библиотекой наверно. Например обновил в ответе с использованием `Raphael`

Comment: именно то, что нужно. Спасибо! И еще момент. А есть возможность запускать анимацию только до определенной точки? И анимировать в разные стороны? Нужно понять можно ли растить или убавлять линию при движении какого-нибудь бегунка